# Django module is not getting identified in basic view.py code

Tags: pycharm

I am new to Python and Django.
I have installed virtual environment , activated it in Pycharm. Installed Django and ran the server.
I am able to open the default webpage by using command python manage.py runserver 
I am trying to create dynamic webpages , But when I try to write as

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
```

in `view.py` it gives an error as

```
No module named Django
```

Tried reinstallation of Django, readded in environment variables but it doesnt work at all.

Do I need to edit any settings or any issue with the installation?

Comment: Is Django in your PYTHONPATH? to check this you can use the following code: `import sys   print sys.path`

Comment: Yes I have added to python path and getting below when I typed that code:  "
C:\\PycharmProjects\\python 2 pro', 'C:\\PycharmProjects\\python 2 pro', 'C:\\windows\\system32\\python27.zip', 'C:\\Python27\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\Python27', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages'

Comment: Sorry, I have added complete path till django and it worked !! Thank you so much @Giordano for the suggestion.